# Using Java to spawn a process and keep it running after parent quits

Tags: java

As the title suggests is it possible to execute another java app from within a java app and keep the children running after main application quits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could do

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

where command is a [java command](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html)

Comment: doesn't this kill child after parent quits?

Comment: This didn't work for me. The parent process was unable to exit until the child process did. System.exit(0) blocked until the child process was stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make the sub-process a [service](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wrapper/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quit the JVM together with the main application, then use Fortega's suggestion (it's probably the best way to do it)!

There's also another approach, if you don't want to create new processes: You could run everything in a separate Thread, also the "main application". This would not exit the Java Virtual Machine, and the threads would run until they're finished (except if you set them up as Daemon threads).